# GATT client not working on BlueZ 5.19

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I'm trying to get a GATT client working on a Linux system that's running BlueZ 5.19.  Unfortunately, neither Python or glib are available on this system, so my only choice is using libdbus.  And did I mention that I've never used D-Bus before?  I have a GATT server on another system that provides and advertises a custom service by its 16-byte UUID.  I'm trying to get my BlueZ-based system to access this service.  I've verified that I can discover the server by the UUID that it advertises, and I can get BlueZ to connect to it.  My client app has successfully called Bluez's RegisterProfile method, passing the UUID advertised by the server, but BlueZ never calls my NewConnection method.  In the options of the RegisterProfile call, I'm setting "Role" to "client", "AutoConnect" to TRUE, and both "RequireAuthorization" and "RequireAuthentication" to FALSE.  I am running bluetoothd with the -E (experimental) option.

If I run bluetoothd in the foreground with both the -E and debug option, this is what I see when I start my client app:

```
bluetoothd[2126]: src/profile.c:register_profile() sender :1.20
bluetoothd[2126]: src/profile.c:create_ext() Created "myRemoteControlProfile"
bluetoothd[2126]: src/profile.c:ext_device_probe() myRemoteControlProfile probed with UUID 119649b6-b656-22ae-e611-ba85a04effc5
bluetoothd[2126]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x950d0: device 24:71:89:09:AD:09 profile myRemoteControlProfile state changed: unavailable -> disconnected (0)
```

"myRemoteControlProfile" is the name of the profile I registered with Bluez, "119649b6-b656-22ae-e611-ba85a04effc5" is the UUID that I passed in the RegisterProfile call and 24:71:89:09:AD:09 is the GATT server I'm trying to interact with, so BlueZ seems to know that this remote device provides the service I'm looking for.  When I watch on the server device, I never see BlueZ connecting to it.  Isn't BlueZ supposed to connect to a device when it sees that the device offers the service that I passed in RegisterProfile?  Why don't I get a NewConnection method call?  What does it mean that my registered profile never gets past the "disconnected" state?  I know that the GATT API was still considered experimental in BlueZ 5.19; should I even expect this to work?  Thanks!

BTW, this problem is nearly identical to the one described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36480516/bluez5-37-org-bluez-profilemanager1-registerprofile-cant-detect-green-throttle . Unfortunately, no answers were offered there.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to work around this problem by upgrading to BlueZ 5.43. I still don't get a NewConnection method call, but if I detect the remote device by the UUID of the service it advertises and connect to it manually, all of the characteristics of the service now appear when I do GetManagedObjects on org.bluez, which didn't happen in BlueZ 5.19.

Comment: You should always try and use the latest available version of BlueZ, especially since versions before 5.4x were pretty bad in terms of LE functionality and stability. Did you ever interact with DBus while using `bluetoothd`?